# Access to constructor not allowed

Tags: java

Hi I encountered this error when I created a custom backbone app for my application. What it does is to send to its parent constructor a target container where the fragment will be installed. The custom class is simply zero-arg constructor and supers an integer to its a parent which stores the targetContainer. But when I ran my application I get a runtime exception.

Here is my code:

Here is a custom class specific to the app I plan to build:

```
public class NoteActivity extends BackboneActivity 
{
    public NoteActivity()
    {
        super(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        addFragment(new NoteFragment());
    }

}
```

Now here is backbone app so I can add fragments at will. I want a dynamic control over the app and fragment using this class:

```
public class BackboneActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private int targetContainer = -1;

    public BackboneActivity(int target)
    {
        super();
        targetContainer = target;
    }

    protected boolean addFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        if(fragment == null) return false;

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(targetContainer, fragment)
            .commit();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(targetContainer);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
}
```

I am still in the learning process for Android and Java and I have a bit of programming experience so I am not quite sure what I have been missing.

The error I get is access to Constructor is not allowed. Is this technically different than other post here which describes access to class not allowed?

I admit I feel so &*&*(& dumb with this error.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `R.id.fragmentContainer` ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace/line where to error occurs.

Comment: That what I have checked as well, it is int. I should be chaining supers for int right? Here is what it looks like: NoteActivity(int){super(int)} -> BackboneActivity(int){super();} -> ActionBarActivity()

Comment: Hi, I will be posting stack trace. I posted the wrong one.

Comment: As a general rule, invoking overrideable methods from a constructor is a no-no. But this is probably not the reason of the error message, just an observation.

Comment: @bizclop, I am pretty sure I get what you meant by that. But I believe I haven't done any invocation of such method on my constructor. I think what I am trying to do is harboring design flaw so I am checking better alternative on my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not do something like:

```
public NoteActivity()
{
    super();
    addFragment(new NoteFragment());
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(targetContainer);
    // you will have to put a getter/setter in BackboneActivity or change access modifiers
    this.setTargetContainer(R.id.fragmentContainer); 
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been thinking as well. Thank you. But I still wonder why I get Constructor access is not allowed.

Comment: Hi, I have solved my problem. I think I have done something not acceptable to Android convention when creating custom classes, I refactored my code without compromising my planned readability and it works. Thanks for the idea. This helped me solved my problem.

Comment: In general, you should not instantiate an activity with `new` and should leave this task to the framework. So if you want to set some attributes, it should be in `onCreate`

Comment: if I understand you correctly, so would that mean I should not meddle with Constructor when is subclass activity?

Comment: I believe so. I would do whatever I need to do for initialization in `onCreate` .